# If/else not working with event.target selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, events, methods

I have three buttons. Clicking on one should do one thing, clicking on the second one should do another thing, etc.

When you click on any of the buttons I'm seeing the same message in the console, which I don't want. Is there something wrong with my if/else logic or is something else affecting the results?

#### index.js:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dtAddClass-rolesgrid", disp._newRole);

$(document).on("click", ".dtAddClass-srchgrid", disp._newRole);

$(document).on("click", ".dtAddClass-additionalsrchgrid", disp._newRole);
```

#### JS snippet:

```
_newRole(e) {
    $("#dialog-form fieldset > #activate-button").hide();
    $("#dialog-form fieldset > #deactivate-button").hide();
    dialog.dialog({ title: "Add New Search/Role Filled" });
    dialog.dialog("open");

    if ($(e.target.tagName === ".dtAddClass-rolesgrid")) {
        myClass._AddNewRoleFilled();
        console.log('this is rolesgrid') // clicking on any of the buttons only shows this message
    } else if ($(e.target.tagName === ".dtAddClass-srchgrid")) {
        console.log('this is srchgrid');
    } else if ($(e.target.tagName === ".dtAddClass-additionalsrchgrid")) {
        console.log('this is addtsrchgrid');
    } else {
        console.log('this is e: ' + e)
    }
}
```

#### How the buttons were created:

```
let _gridNew = _grid.substring(1);
var table = $(_grid).DataTable({
    buttons: [
    {
        text:      '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',
        titleAttr: 'Add',
        className: 'dtAddClass-' + _gridNew
    },
```

---

#### Updated code:

```
if ($('div').hasClass("dtAddClass-rolesgrid")) {
    myClass._AddNewRoleFilled();
    console.log('this is rolesgrid');
} else if ($('div').hasClass("dtAddClass-srchgrid")) {
    console.log('this is srchgrid');
} else if ($('div').hasClass("dtAddClass-additionalsrchgrid")) {
    console.log('this is addtsrchgrid');
} else {
    console.log('this is e: ' + e)
}
```

Comment: What does `e.target.tagName` evaluate to in your `_newRole` function for each of your buttons?

Comment: Those are class selectors. They would be invalid as tag names.

Comment: `('div').hasClass("dtAddClass-rolesgrid")` is selecting all divs and checking the first one....

Comment: @epascarello so once it checks `-rolesgrid`, does it not keep going to check the others?

Comment: It should be `$(e.target).hasClass()` .... unless you really want any div

Answer (score 0):

Here, try something like this.

```
$(document).on("click", ".dtAddClass-rolesgrid", onClick);
$(document).on("click", ".dtAddClass-srchgrid", onClick);
$(document).on("click", ".dtAddClass-additionalsrchgrid", onClick);

function onClick(e) {
  const el = $(this);
  if (el.hasClass('dtAddClass-rolesgrid')) {
    console.log('this is rolesgrid')
  } else if (el.hasClass('dtAddClass-srchgrid')) {
    console.log('this is srchgrid');
  } else if (el.hasClass('dtAddClass-additionalsrchgrid')) {
    console.log('this is addtsrchgrid');
  } else {
    console.log('this is e: ' + this)
  }
}
```

In jQuery click function, you get the element you clicked on with `$(this)`, not `e.target`. Also, use the jQuery method `hasClass`, `tagName` is a tag name of the element, like `div` or `span`.

Or to make things simpler:

```js
$('.dtAddClass-rolesgrid').click(function() {
  alert('this is rolesgrid')
})

$('.dtAddClass-srchgrid').click(function() {
  alert('this is srchgrid')
})

$('.dtAddClass-additionalsrchgrid').click(function() {
  alert('this is additionalsrchgrid')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dtAddClass-rolesgrid">
  Rolesgrid
</div>

<div class="dtAddClass-srchgrid">
  Srchgrid
</div>

<div class="dtAddClass-additionalsrchgrid">
  Additionalsrchgrid
</div>
```

Comment: should really use modern classList and not className.

Comment: Hey @Spartacus, it's only targeting the `else { console.log()` . I know that the classes are correct, so I'm not sure why it's defaulting to `else`.

Comment: Updated answer, check it again. @Bodrov